# Create GeoJSON Feature from FeatureCollection

Tags: qgis, polygon, features

I have a single polygon feature (no holes, no overlaps) which is currently defined as a `FeatureCollection` in GeoJSON, with type `Polygon` (not `MultiPolygon`). I am trying to use it with an [online mapping tool](https://services.pacificclimate.org/pcex/app/#/data/climo/ce_files), and to do so I need to use a regular `Feature` in GeoJSON:

[image]

I have tried a variety of methods to get it to register and work as a `Feature`, including: (a) Using the `multipart to singlepart` tool, which helped it become `polygon` rather than `Multipolygon`); (b) using both QGIS and ArcGIS to make the conversion from shapefile to GeoJSON, and (c) editing the GeoJSON file by hand to make it reflect this format:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [ [0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0] ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "shape name"
  }
}
```

For (a) and (b) I still end up with `FeatureCollection` types, and with (c) nothing maps, despite being recognized as valid by QGIS.

I'd prefer to make this work in QGIS, but am open to suggestions.

Comment: @user2856, Edits made - thanks for the suggestion, and hope it helps! I know that website's mapping tools are a bit buggy, but they are certain that a properly formatted GeoJSON object will work correctly.

Comment: Your mapping tool doesn't say you can't import a `FeatureCollection`, just that if you do, only the first `Feature` will be used. So try using a `FeatureCollection` that contains a single `Feature`.

Comment: That's true. I had assumed that the reason that we weren't seeing anything map was because of the formatting as `FeatureCollection` rather than a `Feature`, since I could find nothing wrong with the polygon itself. In the end, there were two compatability issues that weren't identified in the documentation: the tool only took EPSG:4326, and it only took polygons with fewer than 400 vertices. Neither was related to the `FeatureCollection` status. But your thoughts were helpful, and in particular the coordinate system one.

Answer (score 2):

Coordinates array in your feature is wrong. It should be:

```
[ [ [0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,0] ] ]
```

1. An additional pair of square brackets (because polygon can have holes)
2. The first and the last point must be the same (to close the polyline)

Wikipedia has nice examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Geometries

Comment: Thanks for the response and the correction on the format of my example. The example array I provided above was just dummy data, and it turns out the real example I'm using has the same starting an ending point and the extra bracket exactly as you suggest - thus the problem isn't solved. Any other ideas?

Comment: If GeoJSON is well formed it's really hard to say what can be wrong. From your side maybe coordinates? If the mapping tool is based upon Openlayers it accepts only EPSG:3857 not EPSG:4326. If you use 4326 (lat, lon) try to transform these coordinates to 3857.

Comment: Helpful, thanks. I am using a different coordinate system, so I'll look into that.